# Factor out constant terms with square roots

Tags: polynomials, factorization

I would like to use `FactorTerms` to factor out constant numerical terms out of an expression, this works as follows:

```
2 x^2 + 2 y^2 + 4 x y // FactorTerms
(* = 2 (x^2 + 2 x y + y^2) *)
```

However, this doesn't seem to work if there are square roots:

```
Sqrt[2] x^2 + Sqrt[2] y^2 + 2 Sqrt[2] x y // FactorTerms
(* = Sqrt[2] x^2 + 2 Sqrt[2] x y + Sqrt[2] y^2 *)
```

I'm not sure whether that's the way it's supposed to behave or a bug. If that's the desired behaviour, then what is the correct way of factoring out constant numerical terms containing square roots?

`$Version` gives 11.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 11, 2017).

Answer (score 5):

It seems it works when you specify the variables in your term:

```
FactorTerms[Sqrt[2] x^2 + Sqrt[2] y^2 + 2 Sqrt[2] x y, {x, y}]
(* Sqrt[2] (x^2 + 2 x y + y^2) *)
```

To include JM's answer to your comment: If you have several variables and don't want to type them by hand, you can use

```
FactorTerms[poly, Variables[poly]]
```

to use them automatically.

Comment: This works indeed, thanks! Even though it can be quite clumsy for a large number of variables. The description in the documentation does sound like it should do it also without specifying the variables explicitly.

Comment: @Stan, in that case, you could do `FactorTerms[poly, Variables[poly]]` so that you don't have to bother with manually getting the variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
Factor[Sqrt[2] x^2 + Sqrt[2] y^2 + 2 Sqrt[2] x y ]
(* Sqrt[2] (x + y)^2*)
```

works too!

Comment: Hi Ulrich, thanks for the answer, but I explicitly do not want that `x^2 + 2 x y + y^2` is transformed to `(x + y)^2`. I only want to factor out constant numerical terms without performing other possible factorisations.